# Numpy.hstack() adds the end of line mark to the result array

Tags: python, numpy, pyopengl

i have problem with numpy.hstack() function. I have three the same numpy arrays and i want to join them using hstack(), so I create tuple from these numpy arrays and use numpy.hstack(tuple)

```
v, n, t // rows example [ 0.83468097  0.50044298  0.229835  ]

tuple_stack = (v, n, t)

stack = numpy.hstack(tuple_stack)
```

as result I got ndarray, which rows looks like this one

[ 0.091698    0.69801199  0.88459301  0.83468097  0.50044298  0.229835\n 0.429932    0.989021    0.        ]

Because this stack i use to init VBO in opengl I probably have mistake in this object with '\n' after sixth element. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `\n` in the array itself. It looks like you are just looking at `repr(str(stack))` for some reason.

```
[~]
|14> stack
array([ 0.091698  ,  0.69801199,  0.88459301,  0.83468097,  0.50044298,  0.229835  ,  0.429932  ,  0.989021  ,  0.        ])

[~]
|15> print stack
[ 0.091698    0.69801199  0.88459301  0.83468097  0.50044298  0.229835
  0.429932    0.989021    0.        ]

[~]
|16> print str(stack)
[ 0.091698    0.69801199  0.88459301  0.83468097  0.50044298  0.229835
  0.429932    0.989021    0.        ]

[~]
|17> print repr(str(stack))
'[ 0.091698    0.69801199  0.88459301  0.83468097  0.50044298  0.229835\n  0.429932    0.989021    0.        ]'

[~]
|18> repr(stack[5])
'0.22983500000000001'
```

Comment: thx for the solution, it wasn't mistake, debuger just shows representation of this vector as you said

Answer (score 1):

It looks live you are working with string arrays rather than numbers. You can convert a numpy string array into floats:

```
a = numpy.array(['0.4', '1.2\n', '.6'])
x = a.astype(numpy.float)
```

Comment: v = numpy.array(mesh.vertices, 'f')
n = numpy.array(mesh.normals, 'f')
t = numpy.array(mesh.texturecoords, 'f')

I use this during constructing arrays

Comment: I would check the type of v,n and t just to make sure they are floats, but I think Robert Kern has the solution below.